# 302 document has moved message with Javascript Nodejs while connecting to API using request module

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I'm trying to send a POST request to an API which my system is logged into automatically with my access details.

I have managed to get the request working using Advanced Rest client extension on Chrome, but when I try using javascript (completely new) I get the below error notification.

I'm unsure what this means, when I click on the link in the response message It says `fatalProfileExpection` and mentions privileges, the cookie is the exact same as when I sent the request in the chrome app.

What does this error mean and how do I prevent it from occurring again?

Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="link">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

// My code below

```
var request = require('request');

//Setting up proxy for Request module
var proxyUrl = "xxx";
var proxiedRequest = request.defaults({'proxy' : proxyUrl});

var headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'origin': 'https://xxxxx-online.com',
    'referer': 'https://xxxxx-online.com/x/w/',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36'
}

var jar = request.jar();
var cookie = request.cookie('webRedirect=https%3A//xxx-online.com; langChange=en-us; _shibstate_11111111_1111=https%3A%2F%2xxx-online.com%2Fdwsapps-v2%2Fghw%2Fjrpc.aspx; _shibstate_1509087500_8c0c=https%3A%2F%2Fxxx-online.com%2FdwsApps-v2%2Fghw%2Fimg%2Fpassword-hover.png; _shibstate_1509087522_227d=https%3A%2F%2Fxxx-online.com%2Fdwsapps-v2%2Fghw%2Fjrpc.aspx; _shibsession_64656c6f697474652d756b48447470733a2f2f64656c6f697474652d756b2e6d616xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=_8f156f25083c0adc1ec190b6807d5bf7; ASP.NET_SessionId=w2glfje421wggq0clqd2orm4; lang=en-us');
jar.setCookie(cookie, "https://xxx-online.com/x-v2/w/c.aspx");


var options = {
    headers: headers,
    jar: jar,
    url: "https://xxx-online.com/xxx-x/w/x.aspx",
    method: "POST",
    form:  [{"request":"context","sequence":0},{"request":"getUserDetails","sequence":1,"userKey":116487},{"request":"getStateTypes","sequence":2,"type":"S"},{"request":"getStateTypes","sequence":3,"type":"T"},{"request":"getDefStatesTypes","sequence":4},{"request":"getUserRoles","sequence":5},{"request":"getMiscSettings","sequence":6},{"request":"getRegions","sequence":7,"userGroupKey":51424,"returnAll":1},{"request":"getRegionSites","sequence":8,"userGroupKey":51424},{"request":"roomFlags","sequence":9},{"request":"getFixtureClasses","sequence":10},{"request":"getProviders","sequence":11,"collectionKey":-1,"fixtureFlag":0},{"request":"getVisitorTypes","sequence":12},{"request":"deskFlags","sequence":13},{"request":"getConferenceTypes","sequence":14},{"request":"getCompanyLogo","sequence":15,"paramName":"CompanyLogo"},{"request":"roomCollections","sequence":16,"deskingFlag":1,"personalCollection":1,"date":"2017-09-14"},{"request":"roomCollections","sequence":17,"deskingFlag":1,"personalCollection":0,"date":"2017-09-14"},{"request":"getFavouriteRooms","sequence":18}]
}

request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

a 302 is not an error per se, more a notice to you that what you are looking for has been moved to a different location.
If the html above is the response you get however it seems that they have implemented the 302 incorrectly because the

```
<p>The document has moved <a href="link">here</a>.</p>
```

HTML should tell you the new location in the href.

You can read more about the HTTP 302 code here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302

Comment: There is a link I just replaced it with "link" for confidentiality, when I click on the link, the error on the page is 'opensaml::FatalProfileException'... 'Error from identity provider... Message: Signature required' I'm not sure how to move forward from here, the cookie is meant to provide the signature no?

Comment: Is the domain of the original request the same as the redirected request?

Comment: yes it is, with an added 'access.' in the beginning of the domain

Comment: That means a different subdomain and might require reauthentication.